# How do I get rid of UIAlertView semi transparency?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am able to get reference to the backgroundImageView of the UIAlertView without using private methods etc. But my alpha setting to 1.0 is ignored. The control is still a bit semi-transparent.

Can you help?

UPDATE: I am sorry. The design team provided me with an graphical asset that had already some transparency in it. :(

So actually ,once you get a reference to the background view. You can set its alpha as you wish. Hopefully at least this information will help somebody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image used by Apple is already transparent, not the view displaying it.
So you won't be able to "fix" this.

A workaround might be to place another blue view below it with the same rounded corners.

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated my question. Sometimes it is not obvious what relevant info one should put in it.

Comment: So to sum it up - the solution is either create the same styled image without transparency, or use any other..without transparency already in the image.